Menger's theorem. Question on k-connectivity of a graph.
A graph G is called k-connected if it is connected and preserves connectivity when deleting any k-1 vertices.
The problem is as follows:
Prove that the graph G is k-connected if and only if for any two vertices there exist k non-intersecting paths with ends at these vertices.
This is very easy to prove in one direction: if there are k non-intersecting paths between any two vertices, then by the Dirichlet principle, when deleting the k-1 vertex we will have at least one path between any two vertices.
However, I was unable to prove it in the other direction, since the graph can contain many intersecting paths between any two vertices, and I was unable to prove exactly that there are such k-1 vertices that when deleting them the graph will split into connectivity components.
